# Automatically copying new files to another folder (CentOS 6.3)?

Tags: copy

Is there a command I can enter via SSH (CentOS 6.3) that will monitor a certain directory, and if any new files/folders are created in in, copy those files to another folder at all?

I have looked at various sync programes, and rather than mirror the folder I need to keep a copy of any new files/folders even if they are deleted from the original directory.

I am hoping the cp command can be used somehow, but I couldn't work out how to do it myself.

Thanks for any help, and please let me know if you need further information to help or there is a better way to achieve my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync would do it, it doesn't have to delete files from the destination if they are deleted from the source.

Do you need it to run periodically or monitor constantly for changes? If the latter you might want to look into something using inotify or FAM.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,thanks for the quick reply and sorry for the delay in getting back to you.  I would want it to monitor changes constantly if possible and will see what I can find in regards to inotify of FAM.  If you have any further information you could help with in regards to these (such as setting them up etc. - I'm new to Linux) it would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Just to add, I now I inotify-tools installed (inotify-tools.x86_64 0:3.14-1.el6) - I'm learning!